# Spring - Rollback tests after all

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing, jpa

I want to rollback my database after all tests are done in one class. I tried annotating the class with `@Transactional`, but that makes the database rollback after every single method, but I want it to rollback after all methods has been done.

Comment: Why can't you use the default rollback option after each test? Why do you need such a particular setup?

Comment: You need some JUnit annotations: "@Commit @Rollback @AfterAll" see more in spring test and Junit documentation

Comment: @AlgorithmFromHell cause I need to use entities created in previous test methods that depends on each other.

Comment: Then your tests or your test database setup is incorrect, tests should be independent of one another.

Comment: Well then, how do you test your edit endpoint, when you don't create in previous test entity? @AlgorithmFromHell

Comment: You can use Liquibase to automatically load entire data sets before the test phase and configure it to be part of the build.